# How to chat with another user

Tags: discussion, chat

I am new to this site and just gained the chatting privilege. I understood what chatting meant, but I am not understanding how to chat. Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Find the magical portal

Click the SE dropdown arrow at the top left in the tool bar

[image]

### Enter the magical portal


Click the "chat" button.

### Bask in the glory


Then you can choose a list of many wonderful and glorious chat rooms

[image]

### Wait...be careful in there!


You can also find users on chat but I wouldn't suggest randomly invited people to chat. Some people won't take too kindly to that. Also remember to read the room rules of any chat you decide to join. These can often be found in the top-right of the chat room with the description. If unsure, ask. But it's usually not appropriate to ask to ask, in my experience...just ask

[image]

And in case you haven't seen it yet, [here is the Help page about chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)